# Magento 2 controller redirect on button click in phtml file

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, controllers, redirect

I want to redirect customer using controller when button is clicked in one of my phtml files.

So far I got, controller:

```
public function execute(){
    return $this->addToCart();
}

public function addToCart(){
    // some logic
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart/index');
}
```

The above is working fine (redirecting) when you access the controller via URL (www.mydomain.com/batchorder/index/addtocart).

And here is my `.phtml` file:

```
$("#addToCart").click(function(){
let controllerUrl = "<?php echo $block-getUrl('batchorder/index/addtocart'); ?>"
$.post(controllerUrl,
{
"products": JSON.stringify(sideCart.SideCartProducts)
})
```

The post request returns my logic as it should, however, it is not redirecting. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

> try replace **"post"** to this:

```
window.location.href=controllerUrl;
```